# Does the Javascript thread get inactive before UI thread in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, background-process

We have implemented a task timer app in React Native.

Users can add tasks with a time. When the user starts the time it will start a countdown and once it finishes it will sound an alarm and move on to the next task.

The issue comes when the user goes background while the timer is running.

The alarm sound is not heard sometimes in the background. The timer has gone to minus values skipping the condition to move on to the next task which is

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (elapsedTime === totalTime) {
        runTheAlarm();
        onCountFinish();
    }
}, [elapsedTime, totalTime]);
```

My thought was the JavaScript thread gets inactive before the UI thread. Can this be resolved if I create the timer on the Native side (Swift) and use it here?

Comment: If your app is in the background it may not have permission to make a noise.  The audio focus is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan, Usually the app will mix the sound with other apps like Spotify. But keeping it background for a longer time gets this behaviour

Comment: Yeah, there's two things with that.  First, your app will actively be killed if you're in the background for too long, and restarted when brought back.  This is standard Android behavior.  Spotify gets around that by being a foreground service. So you can't rely on any thread continuing to run after you're in the background.  This includes timers. There are strict and increasing limitations on background processing on Android.

Comment: Second is that there is a concept called audio focus in Android.  You may be running into that, depending on what else is happening on your device.  Without seeing the native Android code (not just the react native) I couldn't tell you if you're properly interacting with that.